# FIFO using Excel Formula or VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my "IN" List -

```
PN  Qty Price
A   100 5
B   150 6
C   150 7
D   50  -9
E   100 5
F   5   9
G   20  6
I   5   7
J   15  7
J   30  10
K   100 10
K   50  10
A   20  8
```

Here is my "OUT" List -

```
PN  Qty
A   120
B   10
C   110
D   60
E   100
J   20
J   10
```

Expected Results -

Manual Formula to calculate Price for PN = "A" = ((100*5)+(20*8))/120

```
PN  Qty Price   Total
A   120 5.5 660
B   10  6   60
C   110 7   770
D   60  -9  -540
E   100 5   500
J   20  7.75    155
J   10  10  100
```

I want to implement FIFO logic to calculate the Total Price in "OUT" List based on "Quantity" in "IN" List.

Comment: why does J come out twice and where is F,G,I,K?

Comment: **Welcome to [so]!**  You might have the wrong idea about this site; [so] is a place for professional *(or enthusiast)* programmers to share advice when a problem's solution can't be found elsewhere. The best S.O. Questions have a bit of source code in them (See "[mcve]".), but if your question covers a ***specific*** programming problem, algorithm, or software tool, **and** is a practical, answerable problem that is ***unique*** to software development, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!  Please see "[help/on-topic]", as well as the links shared with you above.

Comment: @QHarr - you're too kind :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When you have tables like this, the outgoing button with following code:

```
    Private Sub Outgoing_Click()
Dim pn As String
Dim ammout As Long
Dim current As Long
pn = InputBox("Which Item do you want to take out?")
ammount = InputBox("How Item do you want to take out?")
Dim cells As Long
Dim fifo As Double

counter = 1 //line where your table starts
current = 0
fifo = 0
Do Until IsEmpty(cells(counter, 13).Value Or current = ammount)
    If cells(counter, 13).Value = pn Then
        If cells(counter, 14).Value > (ammount - current) Then
        fifo = fifo + (ammount - current) * cells(current, 15).value
        current = ammount
        Else
        fifo = fifo + cells(counter, 14).Value * cells(counter, 15).Value
        current = current + cells(counter, 14)
        cells(counter, 14).Value = 0
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
Loop
fifo = fifo / ammount
End Sub
```

Should be work.
I did not match lie if you have enough in your current list and others so the validation part is missing.

Comment: it was not 20*6, it was 20*8 in my formula....(100*5)+(20*8))/120 = 5.5

Comment: Then I do not understand your table, FIFO is first in first out, so you should have a straight order and take the "things" from the top. 

I and the others only want to help, building lists of the current order which you dynamically change when you take something in or out would be a tactic.

Without your code or a Info how you want to implement your system we cannot help you. To say we understand everything false when we have not enough info is not helping you.

Comment: below code does not work well. it's been built up out of insufficient base data. it seems to work well for all letters but J, but it's simply a fortunate case!

Comment: Edited and add cod, as I saw The letters are fordifferent kind of Items. Hope this is helping.

Answer (score 0):

your "Expected Results" doesn't match your "Manual Formula"

following this latter

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dictSum As Object
    Dim dictRept As Object

    Set dictSum = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictRept = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Worksheets("IN")
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            dictSum(cell.Value) = dictSum(cell.Value) + cell.Offset(, 1).Value * cell.Offset(, 2).Value
            dictRept(cell.Value) = dictRept(cell.Value) + cell.Offset(, 1).Value
        Next
    End With

    With Worksheets("OUT")
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            cell.Offset(, 2) = dictSum(cell.Value) / dictRept(cell.Value)
            cell.Offset(, 3) = cell.Offset(, 1) * cell.Offset(, 2)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks... for "J", its not matching correctly...For first J, it should be 7.75, yous coming as 9, for second J, it should be 10, your coming as 9

Comment: and what would be the rule that encompass both A (that sums up all A occurrences and then divides them by the number of such occurrences) and J?

Comment: This is how FIFO should work, i will take two examples - 1. For "A" - Quanity in OUT is 120, but if you check the IN, there are multiple "A" lines, one with 100 Qty at price of 5, and second 20 Qty at price of 8, so my Unit Price in OUT will be =((100*5)+(20*8))/120 for unit price....2. For "J", there are two lines for "J" in OUT , one with 20 Qty and second with 10, but if you see IN, there also you have "J" with two lines, one with qty 15 and second with qty 30, so Unit Price for First "J" in OUT will be =((15*7)+(5*10))/20, for second "J" in OUT, it should be =((10*10))/10

Comment: for your first "J" example: where does that _"5*10"_ in  _"((15*7)+(5*10))/20"_ come from?

Comment: IN  
J 15 7        (15*7)
J 30 10      (5*10)
  
OUT  
J 20 (15*7 )+ (5*10)
J 10

Comment: since _"J 15 7 (15*7)"_ how comes  _"J 30 10 (5*10)"_, instead of _"J 30 10 (30*10)"_?

Comment: Dnt worry about "IN", i added it for your understanding... End result should be "OUT", where i have 20 quantities first , but in my "IN" , i have only 15 first at rate of 7, so i got 15*7, then i m left with 5 Quantities, which should be based on second "J" with 30 quantity at rate of 10 , so i am in the end , left with 25 quantities for "J"....

Comment: well, if you do worry about any help, then enhance your question with any example to help helpful people help you

Comment: its ok, i will find a way... thank you for the code.